# KeystoneJS: site-wide configuration variables in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, configuration, keystonejs

When creating a site with KeystoneJS, how might I add some site-wide configuration variables that are stored in the database - that can preferably be manipulated via the admin - in the vein of [Craft CMS's 'globals'](https://craftcms.com/docs/globals)?

I can't find anything in the [Keystone database documentation](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/) about this, and would prefer not to use a singleton with a Keystone list (e.g. by implementing a list that has only one item) if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a chat with one of the Keystone developers about this. It's been [widely discussed on ProductPains](https://productpains.com/post/keystonejs/content-management-ie-singletons-like-pages), and as it turns out, having a singleton with a list is currently (as of 0.3.x) the only way to do this:

- Define a new model in e.g. `models/Configuration.js`:

```js
const keystone = require('keystone');
const Types = keystone.Field.Types;

const Configuration = new keystone.List('Configuration', {
  nocreate: true,
  nodelete: true,
  label: 'Configuration',
  path:  'configuration',
});

Configuration.add({
  siteName: { type: String },
  siteDescription: { type: Types.Textarea },
});

Configuration.defaultColumns = 'siteName, siteDescription';
Configuration.register();
```

- Add an update e.g. `updates/0.0.2-configuration.js`:

```js
exports.create = {
  Configuration: [
    { 'siteName': 'My site', 'siteDescription': 'TODO' }
  ]
};
```